# ""Unfortunately Google (or other app) has stopped error.

Tags: google, system-error, xprivacy

I read recently about a privacy app that causes the above error to display to keep out unwanted intruders. Does anyone know this app? I remember something about opening yourself by tapping something 3 times or tapping and holding a button, just can't remember specifics. I know from many questions I read about the subject on here that it does happen for a legitimate error but I know I read about an app that uses it as a disguise, so to speak. Anyone?

Comment: [App lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free) does similar but I don't recall tapping three times etc. Used it way back

Comment: ES App Locker does similar when a wrong pattern is entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One app that does that, is called [App lock - fingerprint](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free).

This app has many cool features. One of them is, when someone opens a locked app, it will tell them that the app has crashed. They'll have to press and hold the *ok* button in order to have the keypad show up. (You have the option to enable or disable this option in the app settings)

[image]